# how can i get the url from a specific image with selenium / python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, urllib

I'm trying to download some image from whatsapp web. I found a way to identify the images but idk how to get their URL.

part of the code:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
    sticker = # <idk how to get the URL> 
    url.urlretrieve(sticker)
```

btw if there's a best way to download the, I'll be glad to hear some advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` attribute holds that information.

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
    sticker=image.get_attribute('src')
    url.urlretrieve(sticker)
```